# Visual Studio 2017 dependency validation project on build server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

The new dependency validation feature in VS 2017 Enterprise requires an additional component to be checked in the installer. It then upgrades your `.csproj` files to include `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets`. Works like a charm locally but not on a build server:

> Error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets"
>   was not found. Also, tried to find
>   "ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets"
>   in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . These search paths are
>   defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm
>   that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
>   file exists on disk in one of the search paths.

Our build server is Visual Studio Team Services configured to use latest version of VS (i.e. 2017). What do we need to install/configure to get it working?

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: I believe it's a private agent `cause when we had access to it we had to connect to the corporate VPN.

Comment: I have the same issue but using a hosted Agent. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 is only required to edit the model file. The actual validation will work on non-Enterprise versions of VS2017, VS2015 update 2 or later, and on build machines that don't have Visual Studio installed. You just need the [Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers/) NuGet packages and the model file.

The *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets* file is a legacy of the old (VS2015 and earlier) way of doing dependency validation. If you look in the VS2017 version of the target that ships with VS you'll see that all of the targets are redefined to say `Building/Rebuilding/Cleaning a dependency validation project is a no-op`. The only reason the targets shipped in VS2017 was to avoid breaking solutions created in VS2015 using the old layer validation mechanism, which did rely on the targets.

If you are not round-tripping between VS2015 and VS2017 then your *.csproj* files do not need to import those targets. You can either remove the import statement, or if you are round-tripping add a condition so the targets are only imported if then exist e.g.

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets"
    Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets')" />
```

On the build server, you can just exclude the *.modelproj* file from the build. Alternatively, you could just tweak the import in the *.modelproj* so that it works in both VS2017 and VS2015, but won't fail if the targets don't exist:

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets"
    Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets')" />

  <!-- In the .modelproj file, we need to define a Build target if we're not importing the modeling targets -->
  <Target Name="Build" Condition="!Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets')"/>
```

Comment: Went with the last option and added a `<Target Name="Clean" Condition=... />` to get passed my errors on the build server. Imagine this will solve some issues for developers who hadn't installed the feature as well.

Comment: When I removed `ModelingProject.targets`, I started getting the error: The target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" does not exist in the project."

Comment: The second option is still required in Azure pipelines with windows-2019 vm image. Kinda makes you wonder if anyone actually uses these projects, since the defaults have been broken for a long time..

Comment: Thanks man -- this fixed my `dotnet build` cli issues with netcore 3.1 on a vs2019 solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio Enterprise on the build agent and make sure to also install the Architecture tools. Same as you would on a developer workstation.

(this is not correct -- see other answer)

Comment: Jesus Christ! That sounds like ten years old story about Web deployment targets. I just can't believe it, install VS Enterprise in 2017 on a build server instead of freaking nuget dependencies?? Microsoft, serious?

Comment: @UserControl It's a full-fledged Visual Studio feature, not just NuGet packages. The general guidance for build environments is to have them be identical to developer workstations in terms of software loadout.

Comment: Well, what is the reason `msbuild` exists on its own, then? Isn't it a claim by Microsoft that you can build your solution either with `msbuild` or `devenv.eve`? And the latter means I have to have additional licenses for my build agents?

Comment: @UserControl If you have a license for VS Enterprise in your organization, you can install it on your build infrastructure without purchasing additional licenses.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't not know that. Need to contact our devops team on this one.

Comment: See the answer above -- on the build server, only the rosyln analyzers are needed. These are automatically installed by vs2019